# javascript: how can I stop a function after specific time from calling it

Tags: javascript, function, dom, time

simply I want to stop a function after specific time like 5 seconds from calling it.

I couldn't find a way to do it, can somebody help me

```
function popUp() {
    // Do some Thing 
    });
popUp();
// how to stop popUp() after calling it after 5 seconds from calling it??
```

Comment: Do you mean you want it to run over and over again for 5 seconds?

Comment: no I want to run it but after five second I want it to stop

Comment: Well, normally it won’t last 5 seconds unless it is an AJAX call? Why do you need to stop it?

Comment: what do you mean by stop it

Comment: $(".story p span:first-of-type").on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('.key').css({
            display: 'block',
        });

Comment: That will run for 5ms max. No worry after 5 second this function will already have stopped a long time ago.

Comment: i want to stop the function it's make some div display: block I want to stop the function to get the div display: none

Comment: So no, you don't want to stop it, you want to counter its effects. That's an entirely different question. Please [edit] your question with these clarifications.

Comment: why do you need to stop it

Comment: guys simply I need the function to be removed after it work

Comment: Kaiido, it's the same I think counter the effects after five seconds from calling it or stop the function and effects return to the original values

Comment: No, it is completely different. To *stop a function* implies that it is still somehow running, like `while(true){}` would. You are not trying to stop anything. Just after you call this method, all will already be stopped. Nomenclature is important, moreover when you don't give any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimout` to run a function after a set amount of time. For example:

```
setTimeout(hidePopup, 5000);
```

Will run the below function after 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds):

```
function hidePopup() {
  // Do the opposite
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use *return* statement:

```
function popUp() {
    // Do some Thing 
    //Timer simulator
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
    if (i == 99) return
           }
    });
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the code can you explain it plz?

Comment: @MuntadarMuhammad In common, if you want to stop and exit funciton, just use "return" in conditional statement

Answer (score 0):

How about you call your function, and then call setTimeout inside your function after 5 seconds to change display to "none", like this:

```
function popUp() {
  // Do some Thing

  // SetTimeout to change display to none
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('div-id').style.display = "none";
  }, 5000);   
});
popUp();
```